# How to display index number in QListView?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I have ListView and iterating over a dictionary. I want to display the index number per row in the view.

```
model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel()
self.listView.setModel(model)

results = {'D2_SMI_1': True, 'D2_SMI_2': False}

for key, value in results.items():
    item = QStandardItem(key)
    item.setCheckable(True)
    item.setCheckState(value)
    model.appendRow(item)
```

[image]

Comment: Could you explain in detail what you want to get? Where should the index be displayed?

Comment: The index number should be placed before the item's name ex . `1. D2_SMI_1 [✓]`

Comment: Note: I have removed the second question since in SO you must create a single question for each post so you must create a new post for that question

Comment: Ohhh sure. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A possible solution is to add the number through a delegate:

```py
import sys

from PyQt5.QtGui import QStandardItem, QStandardItemModel
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QListView, QStyledItemDelegate


class Delegate(QStyledItemDelegate):
    def initStyleOption(self, option, index):
        super().initStyleOption(option, index)
        option.text = f"{index.row() + 1}. {option.text}"


def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    model = QStandardItemModel()

    for text in ("D2_SMI_1", "D2_SMI_2", "D2_SMI_3", "D2_SMI_4"):
        item = QStandardItem(text)
        model.appendRow(item)

    view = QListView()
    view.setModel(model)
    view.resize(640, 480)
    view.show()

    delegate = Delegate(view)
    view.setItemDelegate(delegate)

    ret = app.exec_()
    sys.exit(ret)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```